# Recommended max-width for 1024x768

Tags: html, css

**What is recommended width for wrapper blocks (main containers) on 1024x768 resolution?**

**There should not be horizontal scroll** on that width in most available browsers.

Comment: 960px works fine on majority of browsers and display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you Google for [browser chrome dimensions](http://www.google.com/webhp?gl=us#hl=en&source=hp&q=browser+chrome+dimensions&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=6e1d324e62cc6cd8), you will find a number of sites that provide this information. E.g.:

http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/fold.php
http://justaddwater.dk/2006/08/17/design-for-browser-size-not-screen-size/
http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesignbasics/a/aa041607.htm

Comment: Nowadays it seems easy to answer questions on SO. Just past a good keyword and the first 3 pages from Google ;) But they are quite good resources!

Comment: True - the real knowledge is in knowing the keywords to use :)

Answer (score 4):

The max available width depends on the browser AND the OS. A width of 968px should fit in all system, but a width of 960px has become almost standard for many pages. There is also a page about 960px grid layouts you can find here: http://960.gs/

Comment: +1: most of the grid layouts should have taken this into account, so that is another source for good information.

Answer (score -1):

900px is the ideal one. Hopefully it should come up with scroll bar on opera 9 (It doesn't come up with scroll bar for other major browsers).

Comment: And you flagged your own post for moderation why?

Comment: @Will: That is really funny, but as a programmer, I have to ask: SO allows you to flag your own post for moderation why?  :)

Comment: @Red one less if/else statement in the code?  Actually, it does have some valid reasons, such as when a low-rep user wants to delete their own question/answer.  However, newb here didn't give (any understandable) valid reason for it.